# Best practices on low connectivity?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, reachability

I've been doing some tests recently with an app switching between networks (Wi-fi, 3G, LTE, offline). I've been using Reachability when detecting this switches, but I'm not currently happy with the implementation when the app goes in an "offline state" for example.

I'm basically just throwing NSLogs currently when the no-network kicks in, but I've seen it go off in between switches. So my question... how do you best manage these things? Do you give it a delay in after no-network of a few seconds before going into "offline state"? Or are there other ways to improve this?

Big issue when streaming audio.. I wouldn't want to go into this offline state when is just a simple network switch or small connection loss. One of the things I would do is to wait for the buffer to be empty before changing states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just check twice.  Using your example, when you get the "offline" notification, you flip a flag (BOOL claimingOffline).  Then when your buffer empties you check the status.  If back online, you unflip the afore mentioned flag.  If still offline, you flip the flag and go into "offline mode".  This technique allows you to wait until the moment you really need to know (when the buffer empties).  Otherwise you could use a timer, but it's suboptimal and not nearly as elegant...

Comment: But it's interesting how the switching constantly takes the app in and out of network states.

Comment: It's a problem you can't fully handle very well.  You almost need to do multiple "polls" to see if it's actually changed states or switching...